# Install Shift Email

Tags: email-client

Link: https://tryshift.com/

Shift is the desktop app for streamlining your accounts, apps, and workflows. I would like to download it on Ubuntu, but I am not able to do it. It is supposed to be compatible with linux.

How can I install it on my desktop?

Comment: Apparently not for Linux. Once you click the Download Now this message comes up: "Oops, Shift is for your Mac or Windows computer. "

Comment: "it is supposed to be compatible with Linux" - why do you think so? They offer a Mac client and a Windows client.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Please write it into an answer. It is a valid answer, and the question is not off topic (so it cannot be closed).

Comment: https://support.tryshift.com/kb/article/411-how-to-download-shift-for-linux/ It seems to be possible, but I am not able to do it

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not for Linux, at least the desktop app. Once you click the Download Now button this message comes up:

> "Oops, Shift is for your Mac or Windows computer. "

Comment: https://support.tryshift.com/kb/article/411-how-to-download-shift-for-linux/

Comment: Apparently the article is outdated and they changed their minds. You may want to contact them and ask about it. The result is exactly the same when following the link in the article.

Comment: Do you know a similar app compatible with linux? It is frustrating to switch between my xxx@outlook.com and my yyy@outlook.com accounts. I have to disconnect and reconnect with the other.

Comment: There are dozens of platforms now offering the same integration and even this one can likely be used via web, just not with a desktop app. Pretty much like Google Drive, there's nothing inherently incompatible with Linux, it's just Goggle refuses to publish an official sync client.

Comment: I just don't see how to do it. Could you explain to me in a bit more details?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a forum, comments are for clarification or information requests. You may want to use and actual forum for that discussion.

Comment: You could try Wavebox, it's a similar app to Shift, built on Chromium with a bunch more features and best of all fully supported on Linux. Total disclaimer, I work for Wavebox, but we'd love for you to give it a try. We also have a generous discount code for Linux users moving over from Shift, drop our support team a quick message

Answer (score 0):

I currently (16th May 2022) use Shift on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to manage my email, social media and subscriptions to some news outlets. It is pretty good and I paid for a subscription.

However, with the move to v8 of Shift, the devs have dropped support for Linux. Not entirely sure why as v8 is now built on chrome rather than electron, but that is the decision they have made.

The latest (and last) version of v7 released is available at the following link:
http://www.dropbox.com/s/2k8bei4zxei8jdi/shift-linux-v7.2.12-stable.zip?dl=0
Simply download it, extract it to a sensible location, make the install.sh executable and then it should start fine.
Assuming you are in the top level directory that you unzipped, the command to make the install script executable is:
chmod +x install.sh

V7 is still working OK for me, but that may not always be the case. I've just cancelled my annual subscription and will go back to one of the alternatives (and am wondering if I might be able to get a partial refund as they have dropped support half way through my billing cycle).

Good alternatives worth checking out are Rambox (a bit of a memory hog but very feature complete and easy to work with) and Station (which used to be a standalone electron app but which I think is now a chrome extension).

Best of luck!